# How to find a specific file

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

what i want to do is find anything that has BASH in the title in the .profile folder of another computer user, the code i have is

```
find /home/mintuser/.profile -name BASH\*
```

would that work? When i press enter in the terminal it just gives a fresh line to type in, so not sure if it executed and gave no results or executed incorrectly.

Comment: Why `BASH\*` instead of `BASH*`?

Comment: `.profile` is usually a file, not a directory.

Comment: @ExplosionPills i just read an article on finding files that said using the combination of the two will find files that include BASH. Okay, thanks william, i think i have to search through text in that file. UGH! not the foggiest how to do that

Comment: Just use grep to search through a file.

Comment: @ExplosionPills: If you don't quote the `*` (either as shown or `-name "BASH*"`), the shell will expand the glob rather than let `find` use it as a pattern.

Comment: @squiguy yeah, ive just found a tutorial on how to do it. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use

```
grep BASH /home/mintuser/.profile
```

to get the result you want

Example Output:

```
dennis@dennis-pc:~$ grep BASH /home/dennis/.profile

if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
```

It prints all lines with "BASH" (for case insensitive search use option -i)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a recursive search in a folder for a string, you can use following command :

```
find /home/mintuser/.profile -mindepth 1 -maxdepth N -name "*BASH*"
```

Here "N" is the number of sub-directories depth you want to search. N=2,3,4...

You can use grep to search for strings within files. For example, if you want to search for string name "BASH" for all the files inside the folder .profile, then you can use :

```
 grep -iR BASH /home/mintuser/.profile
```

option "i" is case-insensitive search and "R" is recursive search